# Objective-C: use block as an output parameter?

Tags: objective-c

I know this is very strange and it is seldom used, but just my curiosity, how to do this with or without using type define?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried the following code and got the expected output.

```
@import Foundation;

void moo(dispatch_block_t *cow) {
        *cow = [^{ NSLog(@"Cow!"); } copy];
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        dispatch_block_t cow;
        moo(&cow);
        cow();

        return 0;
}
```

`2015-11-04 09:03:06.829 a.out[50203:2157730] Cow!`

The copy of the block is to ensure you don't set the reference to a stack object which may become invalid the moment the method/function returns.